# Magento 2.3.X Custom Module JavaScript won't load with require.js

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I am building a module, and the HTML loads fine, but the JS isn't.
Here is what I have:

- Vendor Name: NewShop
- Module Name: HelloWorld

File: app/code/NewShop/HelloWorld/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      "helloworld": "NewShop_HelloWorld/js/newshop_helloworld",
    }
  }
};
```

File: app/code/NewShop/HelloWorld/view/frontend/web/js/newshop_helloworld.js

```
require(["helloworld"], function($) {
  console.log('Hello World!')
});
```

I cleared up the cache and everything. I can't see the console message show up, even though the module shows fine.

Comment: firstly remove the $ as you have not included jquery so $ is not a valid parameter secondly add the ; at the end of the console.log finally delete all content in var/view_preprocessed and pub static and redeploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will need to inject the RequireJs module into the page, can you try the deps configuration below:

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      "helloworld": "NewShop_HelloWorld/js/newshop_helloworld",
    }
  },
  deps: ['NewShop_HelloWorld/js/newshop_helloworld']
};
```

Comment: That did it. I haven't seen this in any of the tutorials. Will look into it more, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the JS to the your require JS you will need to redeploy your static content. id suggests removing the preprocessed data first

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

Once you have done this you just need to run the deployment again

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deloy
```

Remember to add your additional languages if you have any.

Comment: Did that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you flush the cache after also have u checked your js has been deployed into pub/static

Comment: I have done that, but I don't see the js in the pub/static

Comment: and you have placed your JS in app/code/NewShop/HelloWorld/view/frontend/web/js correct

Comment: Yeah it's in that folder.